# Set the background image in tab in android

Tags: android

I want to set the background (red image) on selected tab bar.

Initially I set like this

[image]

When i change in the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- When selected, use grey -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/selected_tab"
          android:state_selected="true" />

</selector>
```

Its look like

[image]

My requirement to look like below this. Please help to achieve this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you need to do like this way

For Tab background you need to create selector like this way

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- When selected, use grey -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/selected_tab"
          android:state_selected="true" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/default_tab"/>
</selector>
```

now you can create Button with different layout for your tab button like this way. For this requirement Button View to set your tab icon at drawable top with text.

**tab_add_photo_btn.xml**

```
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@id/tab_search"
    android:background="@drawable/tab_selector"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/add_photo_icon"
    android:text="ADD PHOTO"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:padding="10dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel its nothing to do with XML coding .. just make some design  trick

you need to make two different twiky images  for each tab icon .

- make Image background of tab which have little  **top part transparent**  (Not selected resource  )
- make selected image with same size with contain selected background (Selected resource  )

Comment: But when i do this then its not cover the space. Please look second image where you find the red background color image appear small instead of many blank space there

Comment: You have not got my answer correctly , you dont need to make icon without black background , make icon with those black background and set it as tab background .