# Image not setting to tabhost

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost

I am trying to show my tabs as images not as text. And I am following this tutorial for that:
http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/

Now the problem is that my application is working fine but I am unable to get image tabs instead I am getting tab with a text. I have tried following questions

[How to change the Tabs Images in the TabHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507718/how-to-change-the-tabs-images-in-the-tabhost)

[Can we set a background image to tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756447/can-we-set-a-background-image-to-tabs)

[Set the background image in tab in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500250/set-the-background-image-in-tab-in-android)
 but the results are same.
Here is my code:

```
public class AndroidTabLayoutActivity extends TabActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

    // Tab for Photos
    TabHost.TabSpec photospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Photos");
    // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
    photospec.setIndicator("Photos", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_photos_tab));
    Intent photosIntent = new Intent(this, PhotosActivity.class);
    photospec.setContent(photosIntent);

    // Tab for Songs
    TabHost.TabSpec songspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Songs");
    songspec.setIndicator("Songs", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_songs_tab));
    Intent songsIntent = new Intent(this, SongsActivity.class);
    songspec.setContent(songsIntent);

    // Tab for Videos
    TabHost.TabSpec videospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Videos");
    videospec.setIndicator("Videos", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_videos_tab));
    Intent videosIntent = new Intent(this, VideosActivity.class);
    videospec.setContent(videosIntent);

    // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
    tabHost.addTab(photospec); // Adding photos tab
    tabHost.addTab(songspec); // Adding songs tab
    tabHost.addTab(videospec); // Adding videos tab
}
 }
```

And here is the **main.xml** incase it is needed:

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>


    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Note:**
  And also If there is a better way to add tabs then please suggest it as tabhost has been **deprecated**.

Comment: This might be helpful to you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507718/how-to-change-the-tabs-images-in-the-tabhost

Comment: I already tried that. but same results.

Comment: Will you please, upload your output screenshots ?

Comment: @JaiminModi I added some additional lines and after cleaning the code it worked ....